# How can I get the grad?

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, computer-vision, resnet

I have a resnet model and I want to replace a Conv layer tensor parameter of it with my tensor A and B.

Here is my code:

```py
model = resnet.resnet18()

# my_param = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(64, 64, 3, 3)))

A = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(64 * 64, 32 * 32))) # A is my desired leaf Parameter
B = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(32, 32, 3, 3))) # B is my desired leaf Parameter

B.requires_grad_(True)
B.retain_grad()

B = B.view(-1, 9)

base = A @ B # matrix mm to create 'base'

base.requires_grad_(True)
base.retain_grad()

base = base.view(64, 64, 3, 3)

A.requires_grad_(True)
A.retain_grad()
B.requires_grad_(True)
B.retain_grad()

model.layer1[0].conv1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(base) # replace the params with 'base'

# print(model.layer1[0].conv1.weight)

# print(model.named_parameters()["layer1.0.conv1.weight"])

# my_param.grad = model.state_dict()["layer1.0.conv1.weight"].grad

# my random img
img = {}
img["img"] = torch.randn(size=(1, 3, 28, 28))
img["label"] = torch.ones(1).long()

out = model(img)
print(out)

out["loss"].backward() # I already got a loss func, the loss will be auto calculed 

# print("grad: ", model.layer1[0].conv1.weight.grad)
print(A.grad, B.grad) # print NONE
```

But, the result of A.grad and B.grad is still NONE...

How can I eventually get their grads working correctly?

I have tried many ways:

1. Use `model.load_state_dict()`, still NONE
2. Use model.layer1[0].conv1.weight = base, but PyTorch has an error `TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.FloatTensor' as parameter 'weight' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)`
3. Use `model.layer1[0].conv1.weight.data = nn.Parameter(base)`, still does not work

Answer (score 0):

`nn.Parameter(base)` creates a new object independent of `base`, thus independent of `A` and `B`. Only the underlying data are equal.

To see that, try this:

```
A = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(10, 3))
B = nn.Parameter(A)
print(id(A) == id(B)) # False
print(torch.allclose(A.data, B.data)) # True
```

So, one solution is to create your own layer to replace `conv1` as follows:

```
import torch
from torchvision import models
from torch import nn

class Dumy_layer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, stride=1, padding=1):
    super().__init__()
    self.A = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(size=(64 * 64, 32 * 32)))
    self.B = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(size=(32*32, 9))) 
    self.weight = (self.A@self.B).view(64, 64, 3, 3)
    self.stride = stride
    self.padding = padding

  def forward(self, x):
    res = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(x, self.weight, stride=self.stride, padding=self.padding)
    return res 


model = models.resnet18()
new_conv = Dumy_layer()
model.layer1[0].conv1 = new_conv

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

model.train()

imgs = torch.randn(10, 3, 224, 224)
labels = torch.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=(10,))

out = model(imgs)
l = criterion(out, labels)

l.backward()
print(model.layer1[0].conv1.A.grad.mean(), model.layer1[0].conv1.B.grad.mean())
```